# Android Studio - ViewFlipper - ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, mobile

I had my viewflipper working, flipping between two images. I messed around with sizes and long story short the app crashes now. I undid everything and tried putting it in again, and I can't get it to not crash anymore. Without the viewflipper it runs fine.

here is my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/background"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.melanie.cskiosk.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />


<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="2000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/woit_161013_0749" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/woit_161013_0761" />


</ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Like I said I had this working just fine a few hours ago

Comment: Add crash logs!

Comment: Yeah, whats the crash log saying? It may not be an xml issue.

Comment: Thanks! Out of memory error, my images were huge.... didn't know what crash log was until today. much appreciated